# Why does + () => {} evaluate into NaN?

Tags: javascript

I was playing around a little in my Chrome inspector and found out that executing the following statement `+ () => {}` returns `NaN`. To me this looks like it shouldn't be valid JavaScript, so my question is: Why does this statement result in it being treated like a number?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.jsfuck.com :-)

Comment: @transistor09 weird, I haven't seen that notation before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down.

ECMAScript6 introduces a new [Arrow function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) notation, so `() => {}` is merely<sup>[1]</sup> `function () {}`. This returns a function object.

When you have a `+` with nothing before it in an expression, it tries to cast anything that comes after it into a number. When you try to cast a `function` into a number, you get a `NaN`.

---

P.S. [1] For sake of this example it makes no difference, but arrow notation actually behaves more like `(function () {}).bind(this)`.

Answer (score 5):

You actually parsed an `arrow` function to a number which will be converted to `NaN`

```
(x) => { x * x}
```

this a shortcut for

```
function sqr (x) {
   return x * x;
}
```

when you perform operations like

> > `>> + "123"`
> >
> > `>> 123`
> >
> > `>> + function f () {}`
> >
> > `>> NaN`
> >
> > Similary, since arrow function is like any other function, casting it to Number will produce `NaN`
> >
> > `>> +() => {}`
> >
> > `>> NaN`

Comment: This is incorrect. The arrow function is not executed, it is being casted into a number.